# How to call an instance method from inside a closure?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to access an instance method inside of a `map` call, unfortunately my reference to the instance object is being redefined to Window. I'm not sure how to get a hold of my instance method:

```
class Test
  constructor: (@an_array) ->

  f: () ->
    @an_array.map (value) ->
      @a(value)

  a: (value) ->
    alert value

t = new Test [1, 2, 3]
t.f() // TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'a'
```

[Here's a functional link to the above code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Test%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@an_array%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20f%3a%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20@an_array.map%20%28value%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20@a%28value%29%0A%20%0A%20%20a%3a%20%28value%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20value%0A%0At%20=%20new%20Test%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%0At.f%28%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways to deal with this.

The most common in CoffeeScript would be to use a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to produce a bound function:

```
@an_array.map (value) => @a(value)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6BW8q/

The standard JavaScript approaches will also work (and sometimes would be necessary or more appropriate):

1. Save a reference to `@` so that you don't have to care what `this` is inside the callback function:

   ```
   _this = @
   @an_array.map (value) -> _this.a(value)
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XhP4z/

   I tend to use `_this` instead of `self` as the name for this thing due to the existence of [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) and the *interesting* bugs that causes if you forget the `var` in JavaScript.
2. Manually create a bound function using [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), this isn't quite universally supported though:

   ```
   @an_array.map ((value) -> @a(value)).bind(@)
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/n2XnC/
3. Use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), Underscore's [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), or some other non-native bound function implementation:

   ```
   @an_array.map _((value) -> @a(value)).bind(@)
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAy9L/

Which one you choose depends on your environment and specific needs:

1. If you're trying to bind a function that comes from elsewhere, then you can't use `=>` so you'll need to use some variant of **(2)** or **(3)** above (or possibly [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)).
2. If you need both the inner and outer `this` at the same time then you'd go with **(1)**.
3. If you need to manually bind a function but you aren't sure that a native `bind` exists then you' probably end up with **(3)** and which branch of **(3)** would probably depend on which library you already have available.
4. ...
5. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I can do it by defining a variable to hold my reference to `this`:

```
class Test
  constructor: (@an_array) ->

  f: () ->
    self = @
    @an_array.map (value) ->
      self.a(value)

  a: (value) ->
    alert value

t = new Test [1, 2, 3]
t.f()  // raises 3 alerts: 1, 2, 3
```

[Here's a working example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Test%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@an_array%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20f%3a%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20self%20=%20@%0A%20%20%20%20@an_array.map%20%28value%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20self.a%28value%29%0A%20%0A%20%20a%3a%20%28value%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20value%0A%0At%20=%20new%20Test%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%0At.f%28%29).

This feels like a bit of a hack, so I'll leave the Q&A up for someone to school me in how this should be done. :D

Comment: @muistooshort you should make that an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. That was what I was looking for!

Comment: Or we can drop it as a duplicate, I think I've answer this one [more than a few times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A479863+fat+arrow+%5Bcoffeescript%5D) already. I'm happy if you have the problem sorted out.

Comment: @muistooshort I've used SO for awhile and I couldn't find the answer... might help someone out if we leave it.

Comment: I added an answer for posterity, this sort of thing is difficult to search for, you might notice that I searched for the answer I already knew rather than a question :)